# Processing large API call in ruby timesout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I am working with external api for my ruby rails app. Api call is to fetch details for over 8000 products, and then update into our rails app model. Below is my api call:

```
http = Curl.get("https://myurl.com/resources/Product/?format=json&limit=8000") do|http|
end
puts http.body_str
```

Problem is that my app times out while processing this call. I tried searching for a way to process this in chunks but was not able locate any resource. Another issue is that we don't have resources to pay for large API fee to do 100 calls a day. So we must be able to process entire request in one call. Any help would be greatly appreciated. We also tried HTTParty gem but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My tip is to save at disk and process at your time, locally.

Ex.: create a daily cron job that call a script like this:

```
wget https://myurl.com/resources/Product/?format=json&limit=8000 -O products.json
```

So, in Ruby, open this "products.json" file instead of doing a curl call. After the process you can remove the file, so you know if its a new list or not.

```
JSON.parse(IO.read("products.json"))
```

OR

```
File.open("products.json", "r") { |f| JSON.load(f) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working better than Curl in my case. Sorry it is not letting me accept your answer or upvote due to less reputation.

Comment: no problem. I am glad, someway your issue got fixed :)